# Is It "Wrong"/Bad Design To Put A Thread/Background Worker In A Class?

Tags: c#, design, multithreading, class-design

I have a class that will read from Excel (C# and .Net 4) and in that class I have a background worker that will load the data from Excel while the UI can remain responsive. My question is as follows: Is it bad design to have a background worker in a class? Should I create my class without it and use a background worker to operate on that class? I can't see any issues really of creating my class this way but then again I am a newbie so I figured I would make sure before I continue on.

I hope that this question is relevant here as I don't think it should be on stackoverflow as my code works, this just a design issue.

Comment: why do you think it might be wrong?

Comment: @Alb - it's hard to say. My code works and fills my needs, however, I'm planning on using this in a project that I will make open source. I want to make sure that my code doesn't 
"just work" and actually is well designed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Should I create my class without it
>   and use a background worker to operate
>   on that class?

Yes, you should. And I will tell you why - you are violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). By tightly coupling the class that accesses the excel doc with *how* it accesses the excel doc, you eliminate the ability for the "controller" code (any code that uses this) to do it a different way. How different, you may ask? What if the controller code has two operations that take a long time but wants them to be sequential? If you allowed the controller the ability to handle the threading, it can do both long-running tasks together in one thread. What if you want to access the excel doc from a non-UI context and don't need it to be threaded?

By moving the responsibility of threading out to the caller, you allow more flexibility of your code, making it more reusable.

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question that's asked and answering it well.

Comment: +1 - Thank you Nemi. You answered my question spot on, I appreciate it. I will pull that out of my class and put it in a new class, thank you again!

Comment: @Nemi - so would it be acceptable if I created another method that would would a synchronous load and then have an async method? Or would it just better to have the one synchronous load method and then go from there?

Comment: I personally would not have a sync method and an async method. You are still coupling responsibilities. I have worked with this exact problem many times. What I did was created a TaskController that was modeled after SwingWorker, but had specific code for our app. The TaskController did things like update a progress bar, change the mouse cursor, etc. It may seem like boiler plate code to always have to create a TaskController to make calls, but ultimately the code is more robust and more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks Nemi! I wish I could upvote you again because you definitely answered my question and pointed me in the right direction. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 3):

It's good design to have UI operations operate in a seperate thread from background tasks. Otherwise the UI becomes unresponsive when the application is busy.

If you can separate the part that works in the background thread to its own class the code will be cleaner.

Comment: Though correct, from how I read his question he does not have a problem understanding this point.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was misread. I know that separating the UI and the background tasks is good design (if not necessary, my test excel file is over 8k rows and would make the program seem unresponsive). My question is basically is it good to tightly couple the thread with the Excel class.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate your UI from your background task using separate classes. Doing so encourages separation of concerns. UI code and business logic should not be mixed.

Comment: Just to be clear, my class does not touch the UI. It has two events that would allow whatever is using it to update the UI if necessary, but my class in itself does not touch the UI.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall about BackgroundWorkers is that they provide a number of convienence methods like the ability to send progress updates to the UI. There's no rule that says you can't use it from a different class though.

Also if you're doing iteration that doesn't require items to be processed in a specific order, consider using the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) instead (or if you're on .NET 4 use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I created two events in my class that will triggers on progress (basically wrapping the BackgroundWorker progress event, as the BackgroundWorker is private) which sends progress to the UI (progress bar).